# can i upload posts with the same auto id? swift 4 firebase

Tags: iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

Is it possible to upload a post to firebase to 3 different locations and with the same autoId sense the posts is exactly the same. So I have just managed to let users to delete their posts, but when they upload the posts it is actually uploaded to 3 different locations like this

```
// this uploads the "post" to a global page
Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)

// this uploads the "post" to a specific country page the user have choosen
Database.database().reference().child("AlbaniaPosts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)

// this uploads the "post" to the users uid so all their posts will be shown at the profile page
Database.database().reference().child(uid!).childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)
```

And when they are saved in firebase they are saved as different `childByAutoId` so I was wondering if it is possible to save them all in the same `childByAutoId` ID.

So that if the user delete's a specific post then I can search for the `AutoId` they deleted and delete it from all countries and profile page and the global page, but I can't right now sense I upload the post in diffrent Id's

So if it is still hard to understand my question here is an image of my database

[image: Here is how the posts are saved]

As you can see the posts are exactly the same, but they are saved in different `AutoId's`

> Goal? My goal is to set the same id for the post when they are uploaded at all 3 locations.

help would be very much appreciated.
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. The problem is with how you are uploading the information. Get one key and reuse it. Like this:

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key // use this key for all uploads

// this uploads the "post" to a global page
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(key).setValue(postObject)

// this uploads the "post" to a specific country page the user have choosen
Database.database().reference().child("AlbaniaPosts").child(key).setValue(postObject)

// this uploads the "post" to the users uid so all their posts will be shown at the profile page
Database.database().reference().child(uid!).child(key).setValue(postObject)
```

Now all posts will be uploaded using the same key. I did `childByAutoId()` on "posts" but you can do it on any location. The reason you are getting different keys is because they are determined by the time you request them. Since you're requesting them at different times you're getting different keys.

Additionally, I think you might want to carefully think about how you want to access and modify data within your app. For example modifying one post requires editing the data in three separate locations. This problem could be solved by the use of cloud functions. Another option would be to just copy the "key" to things like "AlbaniaPosts", then you can query the keys for all posts under "AlbaniaPosts" you can use the keys to load the full post from "posts". You'd still need cloud functions to copy and delete the key around your database. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: but i do have a little issus with my query do you think you can help with that? i am trying to make it so the posts are shown example: A, B, C but know they are always shown in a random order exept when i use "timeorder" then they are shown like C, B, A but i would like to know how to make them show like A, B, C so its like in the perfect order

Comment: Yeah post your question and I can answer it. Most likely you aren't looping over the snapshot in order. If everything is done by auto id your "newest" post will be the last post. You should also look into Pagination. Let me know if you post more questions.

Comment: could you please check this question out i think you could possible help me with this one to. thanks.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241086/allowing-specefic-users-to-delete-post-swift-4-firebase]