# Allowing specefic users to delete post Swift 4 Firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

i have just created so the users can comment on other users post and delete the comments if they want to delete them.

but with this code everyone can delete everyone´s comments

```
func getKeysValue() {

   // let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postsKey).child("comments").observe( .value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let commentKey = snap.key
            self.keyArray.insert(commentKey, at: 0)


         //   print(self.keyArray)
           // print("Here is the specific Key\(self.commentKey)")
        }
    }

}


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    if editingStyle == .delete {
       getKeysValue()

        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {

          Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postsKey).child("comments").child(self.keyArray[indexPath.row]).removeValue()


                        self.commentsTableView.reloadData()


                        })
                }
            }
```

then i tryed this code to only let the user to only delete its own comments:

```
 func getKeysValue() {

   // let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postsKey).child("comments").observe( .value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let commentKey = snap.key
            self.keyArray.insert(commentKey, at: 0)


         //   print(self.keyArray)
           // print("Here is the specific Key\(self.commentKey)")
        }
    }

}


var uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var userID = String()
var idUser = String()
var userUID = String()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    if editingStyle == .delete {
       getKeysValue()

        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {

            self.userID = self.keyArray[indexPath.row]

            self.idUser = self.userID
           print(" Here is the indexPath  key: \(self.idUser)")
            Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postsKey).child("comments").child(self.idUser).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


                if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    self.uidArray.insert(postsDictionary as NSDictionary, at: 0)


                    let usersArray = self.uidArray[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let usersKey = usersArray["uid"] as? String
                    self.userUID = usersKey!


                            print("Here is the Comment:\(self.uidArray)")
                            print("And here is the UID::: \(self.userUID)")

                    if self.uid != self.userUID {

                        let logInAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to delete", message: "You can only delete your own comment(s)", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                        logInAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(logInAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }else {

                        let commentSuccess = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommentReloadVC")
                        self.present(commentSuccess!, animated: false, completion: nil)

                        Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postsKey).child("comments").child(self.keyArray[indexPath.row]).removeValue()


                        self.commentsTableView.reloadData()

                                }
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
```

soo whats wrong with this code? the thing is that this work perfect but only on the first row off the tableview that will say that this authorazation code only works with the first comment of the post and if you try to delete any other comment below the first one then i get an error that the index is out of range on this line

> let usersArray = self.uidArray[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]

and this is how it looks in the database:
[image]

this looks like it should work but it does not it's probably something really easy but i just cant figure this out so help would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: It's almost impossible to provide help to this question when you haven't provided your data structure. How are you storing the comments? Where is the UID for the comment? Please post your data so the structure of your comments can be seen. Second remove most of your code. If it's not immediately relevant than it shouldn't be here. Overall, I feel like you've made this problem much more complicated than it needs to be. When you load the comments you should already be storing the UID for the user who posted it. Then just compare that to the current users uid.

Comment: @DoesData updated the question now. i dont know what is not relevant code but i will try to decrease it a bit

Comment: How are you fetching the comments? Why aren't you just saving the UID when you fetch the comments? It doesn't make sense you query again to see if they can delete it when you've already queried the other comment data. Just make a "Comment" object and store all the information in there when you query the comments. Then do if comment.uid == Auth.auth().currentuser.uid to determine if they can delete it.

Comment: i changed my uidArray to my commentsArray and did what you said like saved the uid directly when i fecth the data and now it is working perfectly Thank you soo much once again :)